# Angularjs textarea loose focus on model change

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I have a simple textarea

```
<div class="v3-add-note">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Notes:</label>
      <textarea ng-model="wrap.piece.original.instructions" class="form-control" rows="4" id=""></textarea>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I type model is been updated but there is a bizarre behavior, the textarea looses focus and the page scrolls to top, I don't see any error in my console.

Comment: wrap is an object derived from an ng-repeat directive. 
That for the dom was re-rendered, I had to add track by $index in my ng-repeat directive.